# Azure - Creation of web site 'null' failed

Tags: azure

I finally decided to give Azure a try and the first thing I do - creating a simple web site - fails with: `Creation of web site 'null' failed`. Details say: `Provisioning failed`.

I am simply trying to "quick create" a simple website. Researching the Web, I see other people with the same problem, but no real solution.

I do have an active "Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN" subscription and $150 of unexpired credits.

I must be missing something very fundamental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to put some closure on this, I contacted Microsoft Support and they suggested trying to login to the portal through an anomymous/incognito browser session. Once I did that, I was able to create a website.

Mind you, having cleared all persistent data (cookies, etc.) in the regular browser, I still cannot do anything in Azure, from several different machines. But at least the incognito session is a workable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be [known issue](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13625.windows-azure-web-sites-faq.aspx):

> A number of users have experienced “Provisioning Failed” errors when
>   attempting to deploy Windows Azure Websites. This is a known issue
>   with the trial version, and there is an active discussion thread on
>   the MSDN forums here.
>
> It is expected that this is a temporary problem that will be fixed
>   soon, in the meantime there are a few things you can try: Ensure
>   database passwords do not contain special characters like ', ", =,
>   etc. Try creating a website without a database, database creation may
>   be causing the error. Try deploying the site in a few hours, it may be
>   a temporary problem in the data center.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. This was published 19 Nov 2013. `temporary problem that will be fixed soon`...?